# Cloud Api Gateway not working with ^ special character

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have Implemented cloud API Gateway with eureka service discovery.

When I am calling my REST end point using API Gateway URL with query parameter including "^" special character, I am getting **400 Bad Request** Response.
*http://localhost:8080/gateway/api/v1/test?value=ABC^XYZ*

If I am calling direct API end point without API Gateway its working fine
*http://localhost:8080/api/v1/test?value=ABC^XYZ*

In property file I am using below setting in both projects
**server.tomcat.relaxed-query-char=^**

Please help me what is an exact issue.

Thanks

Comment: Does Tomcat throw any exceptions?

Comment: You need to encode the URL before triggering the API Request.